# Android: Out of memory error when loading text files. How to get available memory before loading files

Tags: android, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I want to load a text file in a wordprocessing apps. But I get out of memory error when files are of too big. I finalized  that I can load upto 1 MB files. But sometimes I get out of memory even for 1MB files.  But I have to say before loading whether I can load files  or not.

I tried for solution of finding maximum possible available memory, apart from freeMemory(),
that is freememory + (maxmemory - totalmemory)  which will give the total possible available memory for the  application. (Say it will be around 18MB to 20 MB). But I get outofMemory error after completely utilizing the heap. say for example(24 MB).

1. My question is really that (18MB to 20 mb) of "maximum possible available memory" is utilized for allocation when loading 1MB file.
2. How much of memory should be available to load 1MB file.
3. How can I roughly compute it.
4. Is there any way out of PSS, Privatedirty. I couldn't understand much about PSS. But I couldn't get much info regarding of summing up in article "How to discover memory usage of my application in Android"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Remember, the way you store the files in variables matters quite a lot. Using char array manually is one of the most memory-efficient ways, but you still need to account for every character taking 16 bits, or 2 bytes. So, if you have text file using some 8-bit encoding and you load it into char array, it takes twice as much space.

Comment: I agree. But I need to know how much of memory is available from heap apart from freememory() to load files (only text files in this case). is there is any way to do some computation prior on it and know in advance . I have roughly made the computation(freememory + (maxmemory - totalmemory). But this will give the maximum possible memory that can be allocated. Say If a file is given, can we say whether this file can be loaded or not in advance?

Comment: I need to know If a file of 1.2MB is given for loading, having 381872 bytes(0.3 MB) of free memory and its loading upto 1.1 MB and given an Out of Memory error. Is there is a way to find how much memory can be allocated from Runtime.maxmemory() when the file is being given for loading.